# field_view_value() with product reference field doesn't display attributes

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm trying to render a product reference field using field_view_value() - which works except for the attribute options don't render.  If it's rendered normally on a node, or in views then the attributes display as normal. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
$product_obj = node_load($nid);
$product_field = field_get_items('node', $product_obj, 'field_product');
$cart = field_view_value('node', $product_obj, 'field_product', $product_field[0]);

print render($cart);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using field_get_items/field_view_value try field_view_field.

```
$product_display = node_load($nid);
$add_to_cart = field_view_field('node', $product_display, 'field_product');
$add_to_cart['#label_display'] = 'hidden';
$cart = drupal_render($add_to_cart);
```