# field_view_value() with product reference field only display specific attributes

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

As previously being asked and suggested in [field_view_value() with product reference field doesn't display attributes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223014/commerce-field-view-value-with-product-reference-field-doesnt-display-attribu) it shows all the attributes for the product [size, colour, etc] I want to only show a specific attribute for instance size within the custom product display. Is this possible and what syntax?